# Recycle Bitmap in loop

Tags: android, bitmap

Here look at the below code,

```
for (String path : all_path) {
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    bitmapList.add(bmp);
}
```

and this code is driving me crazy. As in each iteration BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) is called and driving memory to its pick as a result OutOfMemory exception occurs. I tried to use recycle() old bitmap in the loop before decoding new bitmap but it means no sense. I searched for the answer about using bitmaps in loop but failed to find one. What should I do? anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all bitmaps to a List. However you are using the same reference variable `bmp` for all bitmaps so in each iteration they get replaced.

But in the List all the bitmaps are being added. If there are many bitmaps then it will eventually result in `OutOfMemoryError`

Better do not add all bitmaps in a List.

Comment: Your claim 'However you are using the same reference variable bmp for all bitmaps so in each iteration they get replaced.' is pretty weird. The function `decodeFile` returns a new objet every loop pass. A separater reference to each bitmap is retained by the List object.

Comment: @JaromírAdamec I just wanted to say something like, if OP is gonna process the bitmap in loop and then move on to next bitmap. Then there won't be a problem. As reference variable will be pointing to the next bitmap object and the earlier one becomes eligible for GC. But as OP is adding all bitmaps to list so it is the cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recycle the bitmaps you are not using.
If you use all the bitmaps than add them to a cache and use them later.

Next when you want to replace one you will replace just one not all of them.
The change from below requires a bit more work but it works as I used it with a lot of bitmaps. 
Please take a look here: 
I implemented once something like this:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps can be huge. Why do you need to read them all to the memory? Normaly, you would read each bitmap on demand. Optionally, you can read thumbnails, which are much less memory demanding (`BitmapFactory` enables you to downsize the bitmap when reading - use `BitmapFactory.Options`, member `inSampleSize`).

Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html